# How can I uncheck the mat-checkbox, if I click un submit-button in mat-dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have written a dialog with all selected rows to be deleted from a table.  Now when I submit the dialog, then I would like the activated checkbox to be unchecked as well.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

My code:

```
// HTML

<mat-checkbox (click)="toggleCheckboxes()"></mat-checkbox>
```

```
// TS

private all = false;

public toggleCheckboxes() {
    this.all = !this.all;
    for (const formGroup of this.rows.controls) {
      formGroup.get('select').setValue(this.all);
    }
  }

deleteAllSelectedRows() {
if (rowsToRemove.length === formArray.length) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteAllRowsComponent, {
          width: '500px',
        });
        const subAllRows = dialogRef.componentInstance.deleteAllRowsAction.subscribe((data: any) => {
          let toDelete = formArray.value.length;
          let deleted = 0;
          const deleteRowCallback = () => {
            deleted += 1;
            if (deleted === toDelete) {
              console.log('All rows finished!');
              dialogRef.close();
              this.refresh();
            }
          };
          for (const value of formArray.value) {
            this.deleteRowBackendData(value, deleteRowCallback);
          }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
          console.log(`Delete all rows dialog will be closed!`);
          subAllRows.unsubscribe();
        });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want select/unselect all checkbox use a button ?

Maybe `ngModel`

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="all" (click)="toggleCheckboxes()"></mat-checkbox>

public all = false;

public toggleCheckboxes() {
    this.all = !this.all;
    for (const formGroup of this.rows.controls) {
      formGroup.get('select').setValue(this.all);
    }
  }
```

Or if you use ReactiveForm with `patchValue`

```
  cleanForm(): void {
    this.reactiveForm.patchValue({
      checkbox: false
    });
    // or 
    this.reactiveForm.reset();
  }

<mat-checkbox formControlName="checkbox" (click)="toggleCheckboxes()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I'll create an example in stackblitz right now